# How to remove caption in vaadin Grid multi-selection column

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

When Vaadin 8 Grid is set to be multi-selection mode using `setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI)`, a column is added on left of the Grid with a checkbox on each row.

I am OK with this selection method, but the caption of each checkbox such as "Selects row number 2" etc. is really not necessary.  Is there an easy method to remove these checkbox captions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a caption, but it should not be visibile. It is accessibility feature. It seems that you have something wrong with theme and styles, as this label should not be rendered in viewport. So it should not be visible, it is just for screenreaders so that blind people could use the selection. See the screenshot how DOM should look like.

[image]

> I change added .v-assistive-device-only-label that has all the same rules as in .v-assistive-device-only. Now, both the check square and caption are gone, leaving a empty cell to select. I'd like to learn how to make only the check square to show up but not the caption, if possible.

You need to include `label` element in the css selector. As you see `label` is a child element of the element having `.v-assistive-device-only-label` class name. If you target `.v-assistive-device-only-label`, it the css is applied to that element and thus also the checkbox which is its child is affected too. But when you add `label`, the css applies only for the `label` which is child of `.v-assistive-device-only-label`

```
.v-assistive-device-only-label label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2000px;
  left: -2000px;
  width: 10px;
  owerflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Found the problem with your tip.  The style.css I imported from vaadin-compatibility-themes-8.13.3.jar, VAADIN/themes/reindeer/style.css, does not have a .v-assistive-device-only-label class.  It has .v-assistive-device-only class.  I suppose that's a typo.  After I added .v-assistive-device-only-label class, the checkbox is gone and left an empty column.  Thank you.

Comment: Is there a CSS rule that can make only the caption of the checkbox gone and leave the square displayed?  Clicking the empty 1st column for selection seems not to be the most intuitive for the user.

Comment: "Is there a CSS rule that can make only the caption of the checkbox gone and leave the square displayed?" You probably missed the `label` in `.v-assistive-device-only-label label`

Comment: Currently, the VAADIN/themes/reindeer/style.css in vaadin-compatibility-themes-8.13.3.jar contains only .v-assistive-device-only.  Therefore, both the square and the caption of checkbox in multi-select Grid are displayed.<br/> I change added .v-assistive-device-only-label that has all the same rules as in .v-assistive-device-only.  Now, both the check square and caption are gone, leaving a empty cell to select.  I'd like to learn how to make only the check square to show up but not the caption, if possible.

Comment: I am novice to CSS, didn't know to target the element under the element which the CSS is applied.  This solution works great. Thank you very much.